# Why does javascript only do the line breaks once (The first time)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, whitespace

I have a span.value element, which has nl2br('lots of text') in it, which I will edit with a  textarea, which upon click of a button appears in place of the span.value, containing the current text.

Code involved:

```
1 valObject = $(this).parent().find('span.value');

2 curVal = valObject.text();

3 $(this).parent().find('span.value').html('<textarea style="width:660px; height:100px;">'+curVal+'</textarea>');

4 sendValue = $(this).parent().find('input, textarea').val();

5 valObject.html(sendValue);
```

Now if I enter edit mode a second time, all the line breaks have vanished. I would not like to refresh page upon every edit. Any help? I just don't see what's causing it to behave the way it does. If I enter "edit mode" the first time, it gets the line breaks, shows the text in the textarea as it's supposed to and after leaving it the "edit mode" it still shows the text as supposed to on the span.value element. But once I enter the "edit mode" second time, all hell breaks loose and the world ends. Any help?

Comment: What you mean by "enter edit mode" ?

Comment: I mean the click of a button that changes span.value element to a textarea element with the same content. But it's fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: pre-wrap` in the style of the `<textarea>`

```
$(this).parent().find('span.value').html('<textarea style="width:660px; white-space: pre-wrap; height:100px;">'+curVal+'</textarea>');
```

Comment: Good call, but on the wrong element, seems that for the desired result, I had to put that on the span.value element. As if I continue editing, the textarea always remains with line breaks, but the output in span.value was lacking them. Thank you! Would have never in a million years figured to try this.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the DOM as if it was HTML. The DOM is not HTML. The rules are different. Once a browser has interpreted the HTML, the HTML is gone. It has become a DOM structure. If you later ask the browser to give you HTML, it will convert the DOM structure into HTML. **It is very unlikely that this HTML will be the same as your original HTML.**

In particular this affects whitespace. If you have more than one whitespace character in a row, they are reduced into one. So multiple spaces, tabs, line breaks and whatnot will become one single whitespace character. This will be true in the HTML that is returned to you.

If you are going to convert between DOM structures and HTML, do not expect the HTML to remain constant. You cannot rely on this.

Comment: So how do I handle it?

Comment: @Jussi'lithi'Männistö Reconsider what you're trying to do.

Comment: You do realize , that's the most pointless answer in the world of programming? Take a wild guess if Facebook would've ever been created, if someone were ask Mark to reconsider on what he's trying to do.

Comment: @Jussi'lithi'Männistö No one's paying me to help you. I'm doing it out of the goodness of my heart and because I enjoy it. I'm disinclined to help people who are rude. You want to rework how the DOM works, fine. Go and program your own browser.

Comment: At which part was I rude? By asking how I should handle it?

Comment: @Jussi'lithi'Männistö Have a look at your last comment and consider how it might read to someone who is trying to help you.